# How to get a child class object from base class list?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

Let's consider a sample hierarchy

```
class BaseClass{}

class ChildClass1 : BaseClass{}

class ChildClass2 : BaseClass{}
```

Now I have a generic list of type BaseClass

```
List<BaseClass> sampleList = new List<BaseClass>();
```

And in this list I am adding the objects of Both `ChildClass1` and `ChildClass2`.

Now when accessing these objects, I want to do different operations for different type of objects.
I can easily achieve this using `if-else` and checking if object is of desired type.

```
 class SampleClass
 {
     int Property{get;set;}
     List<BaseClass> sampleList = new List<BaseClass>();
     void DoCalculations()
     {
        foreach(var obj in sampleList)
        {
            if(obj is ChildClass1){//Do something to this.Property}
            else if(obj is ChildClass2){//Do Somethingto this.Property}
         }
     }
 }
```

However due to complexity and performance issues, I wanted to avoid the `if-else` or `switch` (My real case contains a huge number of derived classes).

So to get around the condition, I came up with an approach to have overloaded methods with same name but different types (each for every derived type).

I thought of somehow iterating and casting the BaseClass to ChlidClass objects and passing it to `DoSomething()` method and overloading will itself take care of which operation to execute. However, I am not able to get the object of ChildClass type from BaseClass to work dynamically.

What I have tried is :

```
class SampleClass
{
    int Property{get;set;}
    List<BaseClass> sampleList = new List<BaseClass>();

    public void DoCalculations()
    {
        foreach(var entry in sampleList)
        {
            Type type = entry.GetType();
            var obj = entry as type; //getting error here
            this.DoSomething(obj);
        }
    }

    private void DoSomething(ChildClass1 obj){//Do something to this.Property}

    private void DoSomething(ChildClass2 obj){//Do something to this.Property}
}
```

In above code I have only shown the use of one property `int Property{get;set;}`, but in my real case consider more than one properties in play.
Is there some way to achieve what I need?

Edit :
As mentioned in below comments and few answers to have DoSomething() a method in BaseClass() and override them  in ChildClasses, that might not actually work in my case as the DoSomething() works with global fields properties of the class it is defined in. It is not specific to the object of ChildClass.

Comment: make `DoSomething` an instance method of `BaseClass` and override it in the derived classes.

Comment: @Adrian I have updated my question with respect to why your suggested approach might not work in my requirement.

Comment: You can easily access any field declared in `Child1` from your override in that class. I don´t see the problem. Maybe you should create another question or at least post the curent code

Comment: Does LINQ's `OfType` help here?

Comment: "global fields properties of the class it is defined in. It is not specific to the object of ChildClass." Were are those fields/properties defined (there is no global field property, it´s either a static/instance field or a static/instance property)? Could you show a bit more of your classes?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I have added some more code for better understanding.

Comment: If `Property` was `protected`, you could easily access it within your overriding methods.

Answer (score 5):

Consider making your class `BaseClass` `abstract` and give it an `abstract` method.
Both types `ChildClass1` and `ChildClass2` will be forced to override `DoSomething()`

In case you cannot make your `BaseClass` abstract for some reason, you could also make the method `virtual` and then `override` it in `ChildClass1` and `ChildClass2`

Abstract approach:

```
abstract class BaseClass
{    
    public abstract void DoSomething();
}

class ChildClass1 : BaseClass{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Impl. 1");
    }
}

class ChildClass2 : BaseClass{
    
    private string _someRandomAttribute = "Impl. 2";
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_someRandomAttribute);
    }
}
```

Virtual approach:

```
class BaseClass
{    
    public virtual void DoSomething()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Base implementation for types that don't override DoSomething()");
    }
}

class ChildClass1 : BaseClass{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Impl. for type ChildClass1");
    }
}

class ChildClass2 : BaseClass{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Impl. for type ChildClass2");
    }
}
```

After you're done with that, you will be able to do the following:

```
foreach(var obj in sampleList)
{
    obj.DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question with respect to why your suggested approach might not work in my requirement.

Comment: @JasmeetsinghBansal It will still work using attributes/properties of the class. See my updated answer.

Comment: I meant the properties and fields of the class that contains the sampleList.

Comment: Well... When you have a List of BaseClass you will only be able to access properties and fields of type BaseClass. If you really need specific properties, that only one or the other class has you will have to cast them as you already did in your question. 
By the way: A (working) hard cast will not have a big impact on the performance as it does nothing expensive

Comment: @Dominik expensive is quite subjective and depends on your context and how often you execute the code. Even a simple cast may cost some time if performed a million times in a loop. But I agree this is probably not a big issue here.

Answer (score 3):

You should make `DoSomething` a virtual method within `BaseClass` and let deriving classes override it appropriately. Then you can simply call `DoSomething` on whatever instance you have:

```
class BaseClass
{
    virtual void DoSomething() { ... }
}
class Child1 : BaseClass
{
    override void DoSomething() { Console.WriteLine("Child1"); }
}
```

Now you don´t need to check for the type, as the instance knows its type and thus the runtime knows which override to call:

```
foreach(BaseClass obj in sampleList)
{
    obj.DoSomething();
}
```

You can even make your `DoSomething`-method `abstract`, if you want to force deriving classes to implement it. This makes sense IMHO, unless you want to be able to instantiate `BaseClass`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I have updated my question with respect to why your suggested approach might not work in my requirement